# Restartable HLS encoding in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, fmp4

I'm trying to encode a HLS video in a restartable way so that it can be run on a preemptive VM. It's possible with the `segment` muxer in FFmpeg to create HLS files with mpegts that can be restarted (Using the `-ss [time]`, `-segment_start_number [num]`, `-mpegts_copyts 1`, `segment_list_type csv` and `-segment_list_flags live` flags and a bit of coding) but I cannot find equivalent "live" writing for the `hls` muxer specifically.

Either I need a solution that allows for writing fmp4 fragments using the `segment` muxer or live writing for the `hls` muxer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish this via `-hls_playlist_type event` and `-hls_flags append_list`. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 -f hls -hls_playlist_type event -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_flags append_list -hls_segment_filename full.%d.m4s -c:v libx264 -b:v 20M full.m3u8
```

The generated `init.mp4` will always be (nearly) identical (differs by a few bytes but decodes the same), regardless of start point, so only the last copy needs to be kept. The actual `m3u8` can be generated using code at the end.